# Magento Link to Another Module

Tags: magento

```
$fieldset->addField('orderinfo', 'link', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('web')->__('Order Info'),
      'style'   => "",
      'href' => "*/".$url,
      'value'  => 'Magento Blog',
      'after_element_html' => '',
    ));
```

I have a link on my magento grid on a custom module as specified above. I want to redirect the field to a specific entry on the Orders tab but the url that I have generated is as follows:

```
/web/adminhtml_web/edit/id/67/key/62bc32b0168b446663ef7632a57a903a/*/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/47/key/f0ca76e31666c5bc62d802b0ff8404f4
```

And I wanted to have something like this, the existing url would be:

```
/web/adminhtml_web/edit/id/67/key/62bc32b0168b446663ef7632a57a903a
```

and the link url would be

```
/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/47/key/f0ca76e31666c5bc62d802b0ff8404f4
```

Comment: There is a new site for Magento: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: nice.. thanks for the info Stony.. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fieldset->addField('orderinfo', 'link', array(
  'label'     => Mage::helper('web')->__('Order Info'),
  'style'   => "",
  'href' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => 47)),
  'value'  => 'Magento Blog',
  'after_element_html' => '',
));
```

from: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/665/magento-link-to-another-module?answertab=active#tab-top